# Can a JSP tag access the JSP page instance that contains it?

Tags: jsp, jsp-tags

If a page contains JSP-tag, can the tag access the instance of the JSP class that it is being used in?

Assume we have the following JSP:

```
<%
    String someVariable;
%>

    Hello <ns:someTag />
```

Can someTag's class access the value of someVariable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, because the usage of tags and scriptlets should not be mixed.

If you define the 'variable' as a request attribute, with jstl: `<c:set var="someVar" value"foo" />`, then it is accessible via the `pageContext` in the Tag class.